# How to use AFNetworkReachabilityManager to monitor ip address?

Tags: ios, ios7, afnetworking, afnetworking-2

Currently I have my app pointed at a specific non-public IP address (172.16.214.214:44321), when I'm on wifi at work, that ip address maps to a service I'm prototyping. I set up a singleton `AFNetworkReachabilityManager` as such:

```
+ (AFNetworkReachabilityManager*) probe {
    static AFNetworkReachabilityManager* probe = nil;
    static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
        struct sockaddr_in serverAddr;
        serverAddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
        serverAddr.sin_len = sizeof(serverAddr);
        serverAddr.sin_port = htons(44321);
        serverAddr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("172.16.214.214");
        probe = [AFNetworkReachabilityManager managerForAddress:&serverAddr];
    });
    return probe;
}
```

I start it in my AppDelegate:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    [[HttpConnection probe] startMonitoring];
    NSLog(@"reachable 0: %hhd", [HttpConnection probe].reachable);
    NSLog(@"reach status 0: %d", [HttpConnection probe].networkReachabilityStatus);
    ...
```

As expected, those statements spit 0 and -1 out respectively.

At the press of a button, I do the same `NSLog()` statements. It seems that the async update of those values happens pretty quick. But the values aren't always what I expect.

If I have my phone's wifi turned on, I get 1 (i.e. `reachable == YES`) and 2 (i.e. `networkReachabilityStatus == AFNetworkReachabilityStatusReachableViaWiFi`). This makes sense to me.

But if I have phone's wifi turned off, I get 1 (i.e. `reachable == YES`) and 1 (i.e. `networkReachabilityStatus == AFNetworkReachabilityStatusReachableViaWWAN`). This does NOT make sense to me. If I run my other queries, it eventually times out of course. So why did the reachability manager lie to me?

Am I configuring something wrong? Or is my understanding of how to use this thing flawed?

Comment: Did you get an answer to this somehow? Because I am having a similar problem with the managerForAddress on an IP address.